# Weird coding type convert to utf8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, fonts

I have over 1k records in my database with values that looks very weird:

```
LÆ°u BÃ­ch vá» Viá»‡t Nam lÃ m liveshow
```

However when i view them in utf-8 it looks fine and readable. How do I instantly convert all these to ut8 that looks like this inside mysql:

```
Lưu Bích về Việt Nam làm liveshow
```

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what is the character set for your table/field? is it latin1 -usual default-

Comment: its empty at the moment, but if i set it to utf8_unicode_ci it doesn't automatically change the text for me.

Comment: you can try to use --default-character-set= in mysqldump to dump it as utf8, convert the table type then inserting the data again

Comment: Use `select charset(mycolumn) from mytable limit 1` to find the character set - the solution depends on it.

Comment: @Hawili I have tried this, it's still dumping out: LÆ°u BÃ­ch vá» Viá»‡t Nam lÃ m liveshow but set my columns to ut8 -

Comment: how you showed the data correctly? usually when I use php with wrong encoding, only php will be able to see it correctly, the only solution will be using php itself to create sql dump like, then inserting data into db after fixing charset

Comment: @Hawili - these values/strings are already there like that  - now if I go ahead and do a new insert and just paste 'Lưu Bích về Việt Nam làm liveshow' in there, then it will stay that way. my question here is how can i manipulate a column to turn: 'LÆ°u BÃ­ch vá» Viá»‡t Nam lÃ m liveshow' into 'Lưu Bích về Việt Nam làm liveshow' - because with a meta tag inside html you can convert Viá»‡t Nam lÃ m liveshow to 'Lưu Bích về Việt Nam làm liveshow' np.

Comment: check this trick "SELECT `text`, CONVERT(CAST(`text` as BINARY) USING utf8) FROM MyTable" from [here](http://nicj.net/mysql-converting-an-incorrect-latin1-column-to-utf8/), hopefully it will help you

Comment: @Hawili This didn't work for me. I think i will just give up and re-insert everything manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume the column encoding is utf8. If it's not, change it because latin1 does not have the characters needed for Việt.

At this point what you have in the column is doubly UTF-8 encoded text. If all text is mangled in this same way you can solve this problem by changing the column type first to latin1 text, then to blob, and then to utf8 text. But if some of the data in the column is singly encoded  you need to detect the broken values and update only those. This update statement tries to do that:

```
update mytable set mycolumn = @txt where char_length(mycolumn) = 
    length(@txt := convert(binary convert(mycolumn using latin1) using utf8));
```

Alternatively you can define a [function that does a "safe" utf-8 conversion](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/fixing-doubly-utf-8-encoded-text-in-mysql/), detecting when the original data is OK and returning a converted version only if it's not, and then do the update with that.